# C# - How to declare a 2D array in run time

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array, 2d

I am currently working on a console minesweeper application where a number of mines are generated and each array index needs to display the number of adjacent mines.

The user will need to define the number of rows and columns.

```
public class Board
{
    private static int row;
    private static int column;
    private static int fields;

    public static int Row { get => row; set => row = value; }
    public static int Column { get => column; set => column = value; }
    public static int Fields { get => fields ; set => fields = value; }

    Random random = new Random();
    public int randomX;
    public int randomY;


    public string[,] boardArr = new string[Row, Column];

    public void EnterBoardDimensions()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter number of rows: ");
        Row = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter number of columns: ");
        Column = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.Write("Enter number of fields: ");
        Fields = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    public void DrawBoard()
    {
        for(int fields = 0; fields < Fields; fields++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nField #{0}", fields + 1);
            Console.Write("\n" + row + " x " + column);
            for (int r = 0; r < Row; r++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
                for (int c = 0; c < Column; c++)
                {
                    boardArr[r, c] = ".";

                    //randomX = random.Next(0, Row - 1);
                    //randomY = random.Next(0, Column - 1);

                    boardArr[randomX, randomY] = "*";

                    Console.Write(boardArr[r, c]);
                }
            }
        }   
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: "*however this cannot be achieved using 2D arrays*" Why not?

Comment: What do you mean "declare a 2d array at runtime?" Declare the array bounds?

Comment: Exactly. for instance setting an array of 5 rows and 3 columns.

Comment: *"I have researched and came to the conclusion of using ArrayList of List."* - That's not a question.  What exactly are you asking?  If you have code which isn't doing what you expect, show the code and explain the problem.

Comment: Note that `random.Next(Row)` always returns a number in the range `[0 .. Row - 1]`. You also mix up clearing the board and defining mines. The fields loop should be separated from the row and column loops and be executed after all the elements have been initialized to `"."`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At design time you declare the type and the name of the array. The array object having a specific size is always created at runtime.

```
// Design time
Mine[,] _mineField;

// Run time
_mineField = new Mine[m, n];
```

Here I assume that you have declared a `Mine` class, struct or `enum`. Of course it could be any other type (`int[,]`, `char[,]` etc.).

Also, the generic `List<T>` has replaced the old `ArrayList` in most cases. Lists have the advantage that they can grow dynamically. But this is not a requirement here. Once you have created the array object, its size must not change. If you need another size in the next round, just create a new array.

Note that the array indexes are zero-bound. i.e. it will have the ranges

```
_mineField[0 .. m - 1, 0 .. n - 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You most certainly can create a two-dimensional array with dynamic values taken from user input. E.g.:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of rows: ");
int rows = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of columns: ");
int cols = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

int[,] board = new int[rows, cols];
```

Comment: I've tried that and I keep getting an 'Index was outside the bounds of the array'

Comment: @iMattu please share the code the produces that error. This snippet alone cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I didn't notice that I was declaring the bounds of the array outside of the code, and therefore row and column variables were defaulting to 0.